# Zend Framework _Redirect() not working but header(location:) is working

Tags: php, zend-framework

I just got a new server and zend framework seems to be working properly EXCEPT, when a member posts something , they get a white page because $this->_redirect('/somepage'); doesn't work...

Am I unaware of some php setting or vhost setting I'm supposed to have? Header("Location:/somepage") works just fine.. :\

I've been looking through my logs with no luck. Also, my images aren't getting uploaded even when folders are set to 777...

I'm stumped. Let me know anything you need to help me fix this. It's a large site that is about to dissolve if this issue stays for longer than a couple days..

Comment: Have you examined if the `Location` header is being sent with `$this->_redirect()` ?

Comment: $this->_redirect(); crashes whenever used. I'm a little uneducated to understand how to answer your question. :\ How would I check?

Comment: Sorry, in that case, it wouldn't be worth examining the headers.

Comment: Tried if the longer version works? `$this->_helper->redirector('action', 'controller');` could be worth a shot

Comment: Use firefox and the LiveHTTPHeaders extension to examine the headers or the firebug extension. When it "crashes" do you mean the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

- Xdebug installed? Sometimes Problems with crazy errors
- Check Autoloader, possible redirect helper not found?
- Check Zend Framework (all files available?)

Have a look into your php.log if exceptions are thrown.